# Xpath getting text with mixed elements in same div

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping

Here is some sample HTML

```
<div class="something">
  <p> This is a <b> Paragraph </b> with <a href="/something"> mixed </a> elements
 <p> Next paragraph....
</div>
```

what I tried was

```
//div[contains('@class','something')/text()
```

and

```
//div[contains('@class','something')/*/text()
```

and

```
//div[contains('@class','something')/p/text()
```

all of these seem to skip the 'b' tags and the 'a' tags.

Answer (score 3):

Try `" ".join(sel.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'something')]//text()").extract())` where `sel` is selector in your case may be `response`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the XPath expression

```
//div[contains(@class,'something')]//text()
```

to get a concatenation of the text of all the `text()` nodes in the chosen `div` element.

**Output:**

```
This is a  Paragraph  with  mixed  elements  
Next paragraph....
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what and how you want to obtain. Anyway, there are couple of problems with what you tried:

- You are missing closing bracket (`]`) after `contains` in the XPath expression.
- `@class` should not be enclosed in (single) quotes when used inside `contains`.

If you want to get all the text of `div` element as one string, you might use

```
normalize-space(//div[contains(@class,'something')])
```